# Number of permutations of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ taken all at a time for the following constraints.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of permutations of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ taken all at a time are such that

$1$ appearing somewhere to the left of $2$

$3$ appearing to the left of $4$

$5$ somewhere to the left of $6$, is (e.g. $815723946$ would be one such permutation)

My attempt is as follows:-

Let's say we select 6 positions for $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}={9\choose 6}=84$

Now we have to figure out the no of ways in which we can place $1,2,3,4,5,6$ per position. Let's see how we can do it.

Let's assume $1$ and $2$ are already placed where $1$ is to the left of $2$. These two numbers will leave $3$ gaps.

Now let's try to place $3$ and $4$, they can be placed in $(3+2+1)=6$ possible 
ways.

$$3412,3142,3124,1342,1324,1234$$

Now let's try to place $5$ and $6$. Four numbers which have been placed till now will leave $5$ gaps, so $5$ and $6$ can be placed in $(5+4+3+2+1)=15$ ways.

So in total there will be $6\cdot 15=90$ ways to place $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ per position for the given constraints.

So there are total $84\cdot 90=7560$ arrangements in which we can place $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Now for each such arrangement, we can place remaining numbers $\{7,8,9\}$ in $3!$ ways in $3$ leftover positions.

So there will be total $7560\cdot 6=45360$ ways to place $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ for the given constraints.

Is there any better way to do this, my approach got too long?

Comment: Can't you take advantage of the problem's natural symmetries?

Comment: If you see the solution, in fact I took lot of advantage of symmetrical nature of problem, but that's  not the point here, any better solution?

Comment: You can think of it as $\frac{9!}{3!\cdot 2!}$ becausd exactly $\frac1 {3!\cdot 2!}$ of the total permutations satisfy this condition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, your answer is incorrect, can you see my attempt, you will get to know.

Comment: Ah, the answer is correct to your original question ($2$ to the left of $4,$ which you changed to $3$ to the left of $4.$) As a rule, if people answer your original question, don't tell them you are wrong, tell them you edited the question. @user3290550

Comment: @user3290550 perhaps go and remove your negative votes?

Comment: And don't downvoted answers to your original question. Comment to let people know the question has been edited, not that they are wrong. Let them fix it.

Comment: The new answer is $\frac{9!}{2!^3}=9\cdot 7!.$

Comment: what is the reason of downvote to my question, when I have corrected the question?

Answer (score 4):

You can choose the positions for the 1,2 pair (their relative order is set). And then choose two of the remaining 7 positions for the 3,4 pair. Then the 5,6 pair. Then order the rest:

$${9\choose 2} * {7 \choose 2} * { 5 \choose 2} * 3!$$

Comment: your answer is wrong.

Comment: Any constructive comment?

Comment: see my attempt, you will get to know why you got incorrect answer.

Comment: Is it meant to be $2$ to the left of $4$ or $3$ to the left of $4$? Maybe your answer and question don't seem to match.

Comment: oh thanks, slight mistake in question, "3 to left of 4"

Comment: This answer is correct, unless the question is wrong. It sounds like you messed up the "4 to the left of 4" bit.

Comment: "3 to left of 4"

Comment: I have updated the question, please see, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: I've updated my answer in the obvious way.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yeah, thanks. (I holdover from the answer to the original question).

Answer (score 2):

I would solve this in the following way:

The question has been changed, so here is the new result:

We have $9!$ permutations in total.
In half of the permutations $1$ is to the right of $2$ leaving us with $\frac{9!}{2}$.
In half of the remaining permutations $3$ is to the right of $4$ leaving us with $\frac{9!}{4}$.
In half of the remaining permutations $5$ is to the right of $6$ leaving us with $\frac{9!}{8}$.

Comment: your answer is wrong.

Comment: What did I get wrong?

Comment: updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**This answers the corrected question that considers $3$ to the left of $4$.**

For each permutation, it is equally likely that $1$ is to the left of $2$ and that $1$ is to the right of $2$.
The same holds for $3$ and $4$, and for $5$ and $6$.

By swapping positions of each pair, each permutation belongs to an equivalence class of exactly $8$ permutations, and each class contains exactly one permutation which satisfies the requirements.

The answer is hence simply $9!/8$.

---

Notice that $8=2^3$. In general, for $k$ pairs with no intersecting elements, we'd have $2^k$.